# Javascript - X is what percent of X function/equation

Tags: javascript, numbers, percentage

My script dynamically produces a number and this can range from anything between 1-278.

I then need to do a `number` is what percent of 603.
Say for example that number turns out to be 67, i then need to know what percent 67 is of 603.

The function should return 11.1..%

Basically the second option on this page:
http://www.percentagecalculator.net/

Can i do this with javascript?

```
var total = 603;
var num = 67 // what have been created dynamically beforehand
```

`num` is what percent of `total`?

Comment: `var percent = num / total * 100;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just do :

```
percentage = (num/total)*100;
```

Comment: Of course, how simple! Too much looking at code making me miss the obvious! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var total = 603;
var num = 67 /*whatever was generated before*/;
var percentage = num / total * 100;
```

here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/zfhkB/2/

Hope I helped :)